# Insert multiple value from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the below query to add users to the group in the SQL DB.

Since two columns are inserting from the **Groups** table, I have to provide the group name multiple times. Is there any way to simplify this query so that I need to only put the Email and group name only one time?

```
insert into USG (Id,RId,H) Values (
(select Id from Users where Email = 'test@domail.com'),
(select RId from groups where name = 'Market Admin'),
(select H from groups where name = 'Market Admin')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you can `join` the two tables like this:

```
insert into USG (Id, RId, H) 
    select u.id, g.Rid, g.h
    from users u join
         groups g
         on u.Email = 'test@domail.com' and
            g.name = 'Market Admin';
```

This is not exactly the same as your query but it probably also does what you want.  Two differences:

- If no groups or users match your conditions, your version inserts a row with `NULL` values.  This will not insert anything.
- If multiple groups or users match your conditions, your version returns an error.  This inserts multiple rows.

These can both be addressed, but requires slightly complicating the query.

Comment: @Charlieface . . . I encourage you to set up sample data and run the `select` in the question with `FULL JOIN`.  Then you should think hard about why that doesn't simply solve the problem.

Comment: I'll rephrase that: `FROM subquery1 FULL JOIN subquery2 ON 1=1`